# Anime about a girl with marks around her neck

Tags: story-identification, anime

I saw an AMV maybe a year ago.

In it there was a girl who had marks around her neck. The AMV had moments in which people were guillotined, and it appeared that the girl carried a curse with her, that wherever she'll go, she will bring death and chaos.

The AMV also showed some moments of revolution or something like that.

I wanted to know on which Anime was the AMV based?

P.S. I don't have any idea about the AMV, neither I know what was the title of it. I saw it on YouTube, is the only information I can give :)

Edit 1: In one of the scenes in AMV, the girl is shown wandering through streets (her clothes were torn and old). The anime appeared to be quite tragic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean Marie's backstory?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please don't just post a video; you should also include a description of what it shows and an identification of its source.  (Imagine what your post will look like a year from now if the video goes down and it's just an empty video frame.)

Comment: Oh yes, this is exactly the same video

Answer (score 6):

This might be *Hitsugi no Chaika*. The titular character, Chaika Trabant, has a scar circling her neck. It's usually hidden beneath her clothing, but here it's visible:

[image: Anime still, showing a girl with light hair, pale skin, and purple eyes. She has a scar slightly darker than the rest of her skin going around her entire neck.]

The series takes place five years after the overthrow of Arthur Gaz, a tyrannical emperor who wielded immense magical power. Chaika believes herself to be Gaz' daughter, who was also named Chaika, but who was executed by beheading (along with everyone else in Gaz' palace) during the revolution. I don't remember how much of this was depicted in the anime, but it could be the scenes of revolution and guillotining that you remember.

> it appeared that the girl carried a curse with her, that wherever she'll go, she will bring death and chaos.

I don't think Chaika is ever referred to as carrying such a curse, but there certainly is a lot of death and chaos that goes on around her over the course of the series.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. I've seen all of  Hitsugi no Chaika and all of the context seems wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Based on you accepting [Arrin's video answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/238724/23243), the anime is *[Dies Irae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dies_Irae_(TV_series))*, based off of [the visual novel of the same name](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/VisualNovel/DiesIrae).

> On May 1, 1945 in Germany, a group of Nazi officers carried out a certain ritual during Berlin's collapse since the countless lives lost in the battle served as a catalyst to their sacrificial ceremony. Following the war, they faded into the realm of myth with no one knowing if this group of officers succeeded in reviving the Order of the 13 Lances. 61 years later in Japan, Ren Fujii's friendship with Shirou Yusa shatters to pieces following a certain incident, ending in a vicious fight that sends Ren into the hospital for two months. After leaving the hospital, Ren intended to rebuild his new life without Shirou, but his plan falls apart as irrationality that defies the realm of common sense begins to assault and devour the city. Abnormalities soon seek to destroy everything Ren holds dear before his eyes with overwhelming violence. Even if it means crossing the boundary between the ordinary and the extraordinary, Ren must change though his desires are hardly anything grand. All he wants is to return to the old days filled with simple, everyday joy.

....

> **Marie / Marguerite Breuil** (*マリィ / マルグリット・ブルイユ, Marī / Maruguritto Buruiyu*)
> Voiced by: Yui Sakakibara (Japanese); Jad Saxton (English)
> A mysterious blonde haired girl with a large scar around her neck who appears in Ren's dreams after seeing a guillotine at a sword exhibition. She forms a contract with Ren to exhibit his powers.

### Opening